# Approximation of indefinite integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I found the following problem on my Analysis 2 book:

Compute with an error less than $10^{-3}$ the following integral:

$$\int_{x=0}^\infty\exp(-x^2)dx$$

I have done this:
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to \infty} \int_{x=0}^t\exp(-x^2) &= \lim_{t\to \infty} \int_{x=0}^t \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x^2)^n}{n!}\\
&=\lim_{t\to \infty} 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n t^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}
\end{align}
But i do not know how to continue. Can anyone give me some tips?

Comment: Hint: $$
\int_{2.4}^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - x^2 } {\rm d}x}  < 7 \cdot 10^{ - 4} 
$$

Comment: Thanks for the insight.